# Integrate the LLVM LLDB debugger with Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, llvm, lldb

How to integrate the LLVM LLDB debugger with Visual Studio Community?
Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/lldb/ may help (I haven't tried it).

Answer (score -2):

It should be as easy as opening vs code and search for lldb in extensions.
shortcut for extensions is *ctrl+shift+x*.

Two good options:

- [Native VSCode debugger](https://github.com/WebFreak001/code-debug)(supports lldb)
- [CodeLLDB](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb)

Comment: These extensions are with Visual studio code. I need to integrate lldb with visual studio community not with VS code.